# Proof that $f(y)+f(y+10)=2\cdot f(y+3)$ together with a set of conditions imply the exponential form $f(x)=-e^{-\gamma\cdot x}$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ defined over $[0,\infty]$ and some condition like the following holds:
$$f(y)+f(y+10)=2\cdot f(y+3) \text { for any } y\ge0$$
My intuition is that this implies that the function must take the
following exponential form:
$$f(x)=\alpha-\beta\cdot e^{-\gamma\cdot x}$$
However, I am not sure exactly how to prove this. Any help would be
appreciated. Happy to hear intuitions, references, or a proof sketch
if the answer is complicated.

**Note:** $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are a nuisance. To make things a little simpler, assume that $f(0)=-1$ and $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. I think these additional conditions imply a form of: $f(x)=-e^{-\gamma\cdot x}$ (with, for the exact numbers above: $\gamma\approx0.1801$).

**P.S.** One thing that might help - I am fairly sure the first condition
implies (additionally assuming the function is continuous and infinitely differentiable, which is fine):
$$f'(y)+f'(y+10)=2\cdot f'(y+3) \text { for any } y\ge0$$
$$f''(y)+f''(y+10)=2\cdot f''(y+3) \text { for any } y\ge0$$
and so on for higher derivatives. So, if you can prove it with that information, I can do the rest...

Comment: The space of all functions is too big. It looks like you want differentiability to be a property of the function. Right?

Comment: Your condition $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ is certainly crucial, because otherwise, any periodic function with period $1$ would satisfy your equation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry for the lack of clarity. See my comment below. Assume differentiability and that the function is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct in the sense that a solution of the type you propose exists. It is however not the only solution.

Even the added constraints of $f(0)=-1$ and $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ are not sufficient to uniquely specify the solution. The problem lies in the non-local relation that is imposed.

If we would ignore those constraints for the moment, we could use any function $f(x)$ on the interval $x \in [0,10)$, because the relation 
$$f(x+10) = 2 f(x+3) - f(x)$$
will determine the rest uniquely on the interval $[10,\infty)$. By limiting the choice we can also make it continuous, differentiable, etc.

The addition of the limit $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ makes it only slightly more complicated, because we could take the following function
$$
f(x)=g(x) e^{-\gamma x} + c
$$
for any function $g(x)$ that has period 1, i.e., $g(x+1)=g(x)$ and any constant $c$. Inserting this into the required functional relation gives
$$
\left(g(x) e^{-\gamma x} + c \right) + \left(g(x+3) e^{-\gamma (x+3)} + c \right) = 2 \left(g(x+10) e^{-\gamma (x+10)} + c \right)
$$
which can be rearranged to yield:
$$
g(x) e^{-\gamma x} \left(1 + e^{-3\gamma} - 2 e^{-10\gamma} \right)=0
$$
From this it follows that if we take $\gamma\approx 0.180107$ so that the last factor is zero, we always have a correct function that decays to 0 in the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$. The constant $c$ and periodic function $g(x)$ can be chosen such as to fulfill various other constraints such as $f(0)=-1$.

A particular and simple family of examples would be $f(x) = -\cos(2 k \pi x) e^{-\gamma x}$ for any integer $k$. This family of functions is also continuous, differentiable, etc. and satisfies all the constraints.

In fact "all" solutions can be found by realising that the functional equation is actually a recurrence relations of 10th order and that we only need to find all the roots of the characteristic equation is given by
$$
x^{10} - 2 x^3 + 1 = 0
$$
which has two real roots, $x=1$ and $x=e^{-\gamma}\approx 0.835181$, and 4 pairs of complex conjugated roots. This means that solutions need not even be continuous at any point, and can be both converging, diverging and combinations thereof.

Each pair of roots gives rise to solutions of the form
$$
\cos(\alpha x + \delta) e^{-\beta x}
$$
where $\delta$ is an arbitrary shift and $\alpha,\beta$ are fixed by the real and imaginary parts of the complex roots. One of the 4 sets results in $\alpha \approx 2.11591$ and $\beta \approx 0.249421$. This means that it decays faster than the real root of the characteristic equations for which we had found $\gamma \approx 0.180107$. As a results we can construct solutions
$$
f(x) = \left[-1 - \epsilon \cos(\delta)\right] e^{-\gamma x} + \epsilon \cos(\alpha x + \delta) e^{-\beta x} 
$$
which for sufficiently small values of $\epsilon$ will form a whole family of continuous, strictly monotonic increasing functions that satisfy all the constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I additionally assumed that the function is monotonically increasing. Would that be enough to make the function unique? I am trying to then understand if monotonicity also forces the functional form in [0,10]? Thanks again for you comment - it is very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, even monotonicity will not be sufficient. I added some additional information on the problem including solutions of this type.

Comment: Thanks. Really. Ok one more shot - how about assuming concavity?

Comment: No even that would not be enough. The simplest case of the last solution would be $f(x)\approx -e^{-0.180107 x} + \epsilon \sin(2.11591 x) e^{-0.249421 x}$. For the same reason that we have $f'(x)>0$ we also find $f''(x)<0$ for small values of $\epsilon$, simply due to the fact that the first term is dominating the expression. Concavity only results in a smaller allowed range of $\epsilon$ values. It is rather complicated, not?

Comment: This has been a very big help. One clarification: what do the quotes in the statement "In fact "all" solutions" mean? Do you mean that these are not all of the solutions?

Comment: Yes they are all, it is just that the general solution is an incredibly large set of functions of the form $f(x) = \sum_i^{10} g_i(x) e^{\gamma_i x}$ with $e^{\gamma_i}$ the 10 complex roots of the characteristic equation and the $g_i(x)$ can be any (complex) functions that satisfy $g_i(x)=g_i(x+1)$. This include point-wise mappings, that are nowhere continuous, and functions with divergent behaviour. Even when we restrict the solutions to real continuous and differentiable functions this an enormous set.