# Two "incompatible" recurrence relations / functional equations: $f(y+10)=2\cdot f(y+3)-f(y)$ and $f(y+10)=\frac{10}9\cdot f(y+8)-\frac19\cdot f(y)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Imagine I suppose (for the sake of contradiction) a function $f(x)$ defined over $[0,\infty]$ for which three conditions hold:

1. $f(y+10)=2\cdot f(y+3)-f(y)$ for any $y\geq0$
2. $f(y+10)=\frac{10}{9}\cdot f(y+8)-\frac{1}{9}\cdot f(y)$ for any $y\geq0$
3. $f$ is strictly increasing

My intuition is that these statements are incompatible: there does not exist a $f$ that satisfies all conditions. My sense is that (from the answer to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2377060/229831)):

- (1) and (3) implies the function is of the form ($-\beta\cdot e^{-0.180107\cdot x}$ + cyclic components)
- (2) and (3) implies that the function is of the form  ($-\beta\cdot e^{-0.150939\cdot x}$ + cyclic components)
- No function can satisfy both of these forms.

I can maybe prove this for these specific equations, but I really want to prove a more general statement that if we posit that:

1. $f$ satisfies functional equation / recurrence relation 1
2. $f$ satisfies functional equation / recurrence relation 2
3. $f$ is strictly increasing

and there are no overlapping real roots in the characteristic equation of relation 1 and 2, there is a contradiction.

However, I am not sure exactly how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated. Very happy to hear intutions, references, or a proof sketch.

[Bonus Q: Is the statement also true when 1 and 2 are true over a smaller domain? That is, for example, if the original 1 and 2 equations are only true for 0$\leq y \leq 20$, I think the contradiction still holds.]

[edit: clarified function assumed to be *strictly* increasing. Removed confusing text to clarify that the general case is different than the specific case]

Answer (score 1):

Investigate only $(1)$ and $(2)$ and only on $\Bbb N$ (or equivalently, $\Bbb N+\delta$). These follow a rerursion for which it is well-known that the solutions are linear of the form 
$$ \tag1x_n=\sum_i \alpha_i\lambda_i^n=\sum_j\beta_j\mu_j^n$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are the (complex) roots of $f(x)=x^{10}-2x^3+1$ and the $\mu_j$ are the roots of  $g(x)=x^{10}-\frac{10}9x^8+\frac19$.
Any number of maps of the form $n\mapsto \lambda^n$ with distinct bases are linearly independent. It follows that $(1)$ can only hold if all $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ are $=0$ except perhaps those for terms occurring on both sides, i.e., for common roots of $f$ and $g$.
The Euclidean algorithm reveals that $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=x-1$, i.e., the only common root of $f,g$ is $1$. We conclude that

> $x_n$ is constant.

In other words,
any $f\colon[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ with $(1)$ and $(2)$ is constant on subsets of the form $\Bbb N+\delta$, i.e., $f$ is periodic with period $1$.

If we add that $f$ is *weakly* increasing, $f$ must be constant, and if *strictly* increasing, no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Genuine thanks. 1. Does this always work in the general case if there are no shared *real roots* across the equations? (I think shared complex roots don’t matter because the solution cannot just consist of cycles if it is increasing). 2. What if I changed the equation so f(y+3) was f(y+3.1)? Does the same logic hold? 3. Any thoughts on the last restriction in the specific and general case? I think these two equations can hold on [0,10] because those are like the initial conditions, but I think it can’t hold in [0,20] but I can’t wrap my head around a proof even in the specific case.

Comment: @tarko Complex roots *can* matter as a small-scale oscillation can be dominated away, think of $x_n=2n+(-1)^n$.

Comment: If $f(x+3)$ is replaced with $f(x+3.1)$, consider $g(x):=f(10x)$, so $g(y+100)=2g(y+31)-g(y)$ etc. We'd  originally have degree $100$ polynomials instead of degree $10$, but in principle, the same method can be applied. - The situation would be different with incommensurable offsets (e.g., with $\pi$ in place of $3.1$)

Comment: If you consider $f$ only on $[0,10]$ instead of $[0,\infty)$, the functional equations reduce to $f(10)=2f(3)-f(0)=\frac{10}9f(8)-\frac19f(0)$ and these few restrictions are probably compatible with $f(0)<f(3)<f(9)<f(10)$.